PhpStorm. Fix xml copyright formatting
When formatting XML files, the copyright is moved to the first line e.g.:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2024
 */
-->
...

How to make copyright always start on a new line by Reformat Code... e.g.:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2024
 */
-->
...


In PhpStorm > Settings > Editor > Code Style > XML > Keep line breaks setting must be disabled for the file to be formatted correctly.

